# How to make sure that nodejs cluster assigns processes to different cores?

Tags: node.js, fork, multiprocessing, multicore

When utilizing multi cores via Node.js' [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) is it guaranteed that each forked node worker is assigned to a different core?

If it's not guaranteed is there any way to control or manage it and eventually guarantee that all end up in different cores? Or the OS' scheduler distributes them evenly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago I did some tests with cluster module which you can check in this [post](http://codeplease.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/cluster-api/) that I wrote. Looking at the system monitor screenshots it is this pretty straightforward to understand what happens under the hood (with and without cluster module).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed up to the OS to distribute processes over the cores. You could obtain the [`pid`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid) of a child process and use an [external utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-set-the-processor-affinity-of-a-process-on-linux) to set the CPU affinity of that process. That would, of course, not be very portable.